Create a domain that works inside local network website hosted on iis
I have a website setup in IIS with the name lansite.int, the site works when I enter its address: https://lansite.int to addressbar but first I need to accept its certificate in browser warning page.
I want to setup a certificate for this site using Let's Encrypt certbot, but it commplains about nonexisting domain name. so I need to make a local domain for this site that binds to 127.0.0.1. with the same name as the site (lansite.int), and will be accessible from other network computers.
I searched alot but didn't find how to do this in windows server 2019 ServerManager => DNS, That is installed on the server.
Please help.

This site only covers programming questions, so server administraton or certbot configuration is considered off topic.
